# Can SSRS dataset have a default value?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

My `SSRS` report has one dataset (`datasetMacys`) that calls `usp_GetStoreSales @Rundate, @StoreName`.

Can the dataset have a default value? That way the report will only ask for one parameter (`@Rundate`) and the dataset has the string value "Macys" embedded?

In other words, the user will not have to select a value for the second parameter because it's already the default value of that dataset.

I would then add a 2nd dataset (`datasetSears`) where the default value for @StoreName is "Sears", which means it will only use the `@Rundate` that the user selected.

The stored procedure looks like this, even though it's not really needed for the question:

```
create procedure usp_GetStoreSales 
(
    @RunDate date,
    @StoreName varchar(10)
)
as

select * from [Sales] 
where RunDate = @RunDate and StoreName = @StoreName
```

I can easily fix this problem by creating two different stored procedures (ie. `usp_GetMacysSales @RunDate` and `usp_GetSearsSales @RunDate`), but that's exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: Are you looking for [default values for parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-change-or-delete-default-values-for-a-report-parameter?view=sql-server-2017#to-add-or-change-the-default-values-for-a-report-parameter)?

Comment: No, because the default value will affect the whole report. It would be a default value for one dataset.

Comment: The user selects a date, and one dataset will use _the selected date_ and parameter `Sears` while the other dataset will use _the selected date_ and parameter `Macys`

Comment: Are both of these datasets going to be executed irrespective of anything else? Are there tables bound to both of those datasets and both of them should show data every time the user looks at the report?

Comment: Hi - is it possible to change procedure so it will get only one parameters and it will check its dataset? Or write sth like proxy-proc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create your two datasets and then, for each dataset, righ click the dataset name, choose properties, click the parameters tab and overwrite the parameter value for the StoreName parameter.

Comment: Thanks. I had set the expression to `"Macys"` and it wasn't working.

Comment: What did work was setting the `expression` to `="Macys"`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you can have a default value for the parameter of a dataset.

In the Parameters tab of the Dataset Properties, you can type in (hard code) a value in the Parameter Value expression box.

[image]

Of course the next question would be WHY? There may be better ways to do it.

If you are going to have both sets of data, why not make a query that combines the data  into one so you only have one dataset?

Comment: There's more than two sets of data. It would just be too many `joins`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the printscreen.